# How to return an XML with node-soap server?

Tags: c#, node.js, soap, soap-client, node-soap

I'm making a NodeJS web service that contains API REST and SOAP methods (Im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) with Express.  With API REST I don't have any problem but with SOAP I have an inconvenient, when I try to consume the SOAP method from a testing C# application I can see that the parameters are going fine, but in the response I have the next error in C# (Response is not correct XML code)

[image]

When I consume the method from a NodeJS client with node-soap too the response working fine.

Part of my NodeJS code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const soap = require('soap');
const fs = require('fs');

const xml = fs.readFileSync('src/templates/ws_soap.wsdl', 'utf8');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const soap_service = {
  integrations: {
    pull: {
      getSnapshotGIGA: function(args) {
        return {
          res: "HOLA"
        };
      },
    }
  }
};

app.listen(port, ip, function() {

  soap.listen(app, '/integrations_service', soap_service, xml, function() {
    console.log('SOAP web service started on ' + ip + ':' + port);
  });

  console.log('API REST started on ' + ip + ':' + port);
});
```

My WSDL file is next (In response I have the type string because I wanted to see how it behaved, but I need to return an object XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="integrations_service" targetNamespace="http://localhost:4205/integrations_service" xmlns="http://localhost:4205/integrations_service" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:message name="getSnapshotGIGARequest">
    <wsdl:part name="User" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getSnapshotGIGAResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="res" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="pull_integrations">
    <wsdl:operation name="getSnapshotGIGA">
      <wsdl:input message="getSnapshotGIGARequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="getSnapshotGIGAResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="pull_integrations_binding" type="pull_integrations">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getSnapshotGIGA">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getSnapshotGIGA"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="integrations">
    <wsdl:port binding="pull_integrations_binding" name="pull">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:4205/integrations_service"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

In C# I have an console application and I have registered the SOAP service as a web referency.

[image]

The way I consume the SOAP method is (When I make a SOAP Service with C# I test methods from this way too because is the way clients working):

```
Console.WriteLine("Consume NodeJS SOAP service");
Thread.Sleep(500);
integrations_service.integrations integrations = new integrations_service.integrations();
integrations.Url = "http://localhost:4205/integrations_service?wsdl";
var some_response = integrations.getSnapshotGIGA("myuser", "123456");
Console.WriteLine("Press enter to out...");
```

I want to get the response in and XmlNode like in this example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Consume C# SOAP service");
Thread.Sleep(500);
serviceSOAP sSOAP = new serviceSOAP ();
sSOAP.Url = "http://my.domain.com.mx/";
XmlNode xmlNode = sSOAP .anyMethodSoap("yomero", "123456");
Console.WriteLine(XElement.Parse(xmlNode.OuterXml).ToString());
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

If you know how I can return the XML from NodeJS and get it correctly in C# or any idea, I would appreciate it.  Reggards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question, the problem was the WSDL configuration.  With this configuration I made this works with C# web reference.  The principal problem, the style, I changed it from "rpc" to "document" and configure correctly the element for the response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
  name="devices_service"
  targetNamespace="http://localhost:4205/devices_service"
  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
  xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://localhost:4205/devices_service">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost:4205/devices_service" xmlns="http://localhost:4205/devices_service" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xs:element name="GetDevicesRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="GetDevicesResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetDevicesSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="GetDevicesRequest"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetDevicesSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="GetDevicesResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="user_devices">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetDevices">
      <wsdl:input message="GetDevicesSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="GetDevicesSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="user_devices_binding" type="user_devices">
    <s:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetDevices">
      <s:operation soapAction="http://localhost:4205/devices_services/GetDevices"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <s:body use="literal" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <s:body use="literal" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="devices">
    <wsdl:port binding="user_devices_binding" name="user">
      <s:address location="http://localhost:4205/devices_service"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>**
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use one of:

node-soap
strong-soap (rewrite of node-soap)
easysoap